# Share Internet connection from a Debian laptop to a FreeBSD desktop

Tags: networking, debian, freebsd, internet, bridge

I have this situation: My Debian laptop is connected to the Internet via its wlan interface through my wireless router. Recently I decided to install FreeBSD on a very old machine (a celeron 300Mhz) which has only one ethernet interface.

I can't connect this desktop (celeron) to the router (distance and cable concerns), so I was wondering how to make the Debian laptop share its Internet access with the FreeBSD desktop with a little cable.

I've read about [network bridging](http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections) and think I can do that on the Debian side, but I still wonder how to proceed on the FreeBSD celeron desktop. How can I let this celeron access the Internet so I can upgrade/install stuff on it?

Answer (score 3):

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or edit /etc/sysctl.conf and set 1 to the net.ipv4.ip_forward (It should be net.ipv4.ip_forward=1). This will make that change persistant after a reboot.

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(or you can save it in rc.local file)

eth0 - replace with your Dell Wifi port

connect the two machines with crosover LAN cable

Comment: Thanks, @jet! I can in fact edit my current firewall script  and add what you suggested. But do I still have to do the bridging? (I guess I should, right?)

Comment: nope, that is enough